# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Tags: mysql, apache, mysqli, php

I have a really strange error. My httpd server have been working fine until last Wednesday, when I uninstalled the MS SQL and visual studio C#. When I restarted the PC, Ii discovered that some parts of the Environment variable PATH disappeared...Almost all the problems where recovered, The only one that cannot be adjusted is my httpd server... or the PHP configuration, I don't know.
I have already uninstalled the Apache server, PHP and MySql and resintalled them again... I have done this lots of times on other PCs so I'm sure that it should work...but I'm missing something.

The worst thing is that the data I get  when I do in cmd "php -i" is different form the data I get form a page info.php like this:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

The page doesn't show any info about the mysqli configuration...

can any body help me?
I'm trying anything to avoid formatting the PC!!!

Thanks in advance

Update::::::::::::::::::::::::::
With phpinfo I find:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   C:\PHP\php.ini
```

In C:\windows there's no php.ini file. Where else can PHP find other configurations?

Comment: Open your `php.ini()` - there should be a line pointing to `mysqli.dll`. Uncomment that and restart, and you should be good to go

Comment: PHP normally has two ini files. One for running inside webservers, and one for commandline operation. Getting different output isn't a problem in and of itself, since the web side of things does require some different options than cli (e.g. the cli doesn't need sessions auto started).

Comment: I have already uncommented the mysqli.dll line, and the file is where it has to be. That's the problem...

Answer (score 6):

Open the folder you installed PHP
Edit php.ini file

If no php.ini exists, copy one of the php.ini/Production/Development to php.ini

```
uncomment
    extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

if you have not installed php in the default folder...
or if you have the php extensions in a separated folder
change the extension_dir to the correct path

```
change
    extension_dir = "C:/APL/php/ext/"
```

Comment: This sounds stupid, but when upgrading PHP, it's a compulsory to check line by line of the new PHP.INI (if we're switching to new php.ini as well).

I didn't noticed the extension_dir was commented (previous php.ini was properly pointed to "ext" directory.

Thanks and +1 to your solution.

Comment: quick, if you on linux. My case i use 7.2, so `apt install php7.2-mysql`

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo I updated apt install php7.2-mysql still getting the same error